# Breaking an include

Tags: php

When you want to omit the remaining of a loop you write a break statement.

Is there something that you can write to omit the remaining of an included file (but not terminate the rest of the app like when using `die` or `exit`)?

Comment: I'm really not sure why you'd want to. (What's in the include file?) I'm sort of hoping it's functions or a class, but I guess that's not the case in this instance.

Comment: @middaparka, It's for a particular type of files that are being included by default by the environment they are in. There are a few occasions when executing all the code in these files is not necessary and that's why I wanted this.

Comment: @Emanuil Sounds like you just need to wrap the relevant portions in an *if* block depending on the currently active page, etc.

Comment: @middaparka, Sure, that would work. I was curious to know, though, whether a more elegant approach was available.

Comment: @Emanuil I'd have thought it would be neater to wrap the relevant content in a function/method and simply call that function/method. (There's no reason why all of this can't occur inside the included file is so required.)

Comment: @middaparka, Say you've got a function `foo($value)` and it should execute only if `$value` is not `null`. You've got 2 obvious way to handle that. [1] `if($value !== null){ // all the code that could be a lot }` or [2] `if($value === null) return`. Which one would you go for?

Comment: @Emanuil It really depends on what's the sensible default for the function/method. (I'd handle the "default" case first.) However, if you're worrying about which to put first for performance reasons, then don't. The amount of time saved is meaningless - the legibility and maintainability of the code is considerably more important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `return` statement to exit an included file, and optionally return a value.

Example:

```
<?php
// file1.php:

$value = include('file2.php');
echo $value;
```

Which includes:

```
<?php
// file2.php:
if($_REQUEST['something'] == 'something else')
  return 'Something else';

//do some stuff if _REQUEST['something'] != 'something else'

return 'something';
```

Obviously a useless example, but, it demonstrates the use of `return` to eit an `include()`ed file.

Comment: Brilliant! I was almost sure it can't be done but it turns out there is such an elegant solution. I'm so glad I asked this question.

Comment: +1. Though, close your PHP tags for good form and general sanity.

Comment: @Tomalak: for PHP only files I always omit the closing PHP tag. This is also the [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html) and [Drupal](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#phptags) standard.

Answer (score 1):

you could split your include into two separate files, then require the two as necessary instead of just one, or possibly just require the one and have that one require the second as necessary.

Comment: You could also structure your code in the included file using `if` statements... there's a wide variety of ways to handle this.